# A saga for others sagas

Tags: redux-saga

I am finding difficulty in how to organize code in `redux-saga`. I have this particular saga that makes http requests (and a lot of other work).

I do not want it to be an imperative function, but I also do not want to be too confusing.

At the moment I have created a saga that will be invoked by this action:

```
export const makeServerRequest = (options, success, error) => ({type: MAKE_REQUEST, options, success, error});
```

The saga is something like that:

```
function *makeRequestSaga(action) {
    try {
        // saga magic
        yield put(action.success(response));
    } catch (error) {
        yield put(action.error(error));
    }
}

function *serverSagasWatcher() {
    yield takeEvery(MAKE_REQUEST, makeRequestSaga);
}
```

The problem with this approach I find difficult to follow the logic, and it seems to me to be back to callbacks time.

The action is invoked in this way by other sagas:

```
yield put(makeServerRequest(options, loginSuccessful, loginError));

function *loginSuccessfulSaga(action) {
    console.log('Success');
}

function *loginErrorSaga(action) {
    console.log('Login error');
}
```

In this way I have anyway a lot more watchers (every saga which do a request needs to define two actions and run two watchers, one for every return function).

What's the best practice for this use case?

I can also do *real* callbacks, but the problem then is the generator will stay alive until the callback is ended, so if there is an infinite loop in the callback then the generator will hang forever.

If I need to do the make request imperative, then what's the advantage of `redux-saga` over `redux-thunk`?

I an sure I am missing something very easy about this, but I do not find any solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, you generally don't need such construction. Instead you execute the sequence of actions in one function the generator in the unit TRY/catch, and asynchrony and waiting is reached by means of construction of yield + Promise.

Maybe you meant following solution ?

```
function makeServerRequest(options) {
    return fetch(options) /* Or more complex fetch logic */
        .then((result) => {
            let isOkay = true, errorMessage = null
            /* Implement your verification logic here */
            return isOkay
                ? Promise.resolve(result)
                : Promise.reject(errorMessage)
        })
}

function * makeRequestSaga(action) {
    try {
        yield call(makeServerRequest(options));
        yield put(action.success(response));
    } catch (error) {
        yield put(action.error(error));
    }
}
```